# Mysql & Vb.net 'Invalid Attempt to Read when reader is closed'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have run into this error while collecting data from a mysql database and placing it into a DataView control... This is my code:

```
    Private Function PopulateActivity()
    Dim loginStatement As String = "SELECT * FROM activity WHERE id = @userid"

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(loginStatement, mainconn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", LoggedInUser.ID)

    Dim drMyAcount As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Dim rowCount As Integer = 0
    Dim rowAmount As Integer = 0
    'gets count of rows returned from mysql query'
    Using dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(drMyAcount)
        rowAmount = dt.Rows.Count
    End Using
    'adds an entry for each item returned from the mysql query'
    Do While rowCount < rowAmount
        drMyAcount.Read() 'HERE IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS'
        Dim tempDateTime As String = drMyAcount.Item("dateTime")
        Dim tempInfo As String = drMyAcount.Item("info")
        Dim tempBalChanges As String = drMyAcount.Item("balChange")
        Dim tempToFrom As String = drMyAcount.Item("toFrom")
        ActivityView.Rows.Add(tempDateTime, tempInfo, tempBalChanges, tempToFrom)
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
    Loop
    drMyAcount.Close()
    Return 0
    End Function
```

I am unaware of why this is but it gives me an 'Invalid Attempt to Read when reader is closed' error one the:

```
drMyAccount.Read()
```

line...

I would appreciate any help on this topic! Thanks Much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take out the `dt.Load()` , and counting of the rows prior to using datareader.  DataReader has a built in property of `.HasRows`

```
if (drMyAcount.HasRows)            
    while (drMyAcount.Read())            
         Dim tempDateTime As String = drMyAcount.Item("dateTime")
         Dim tempInfo As String = drMyAcount.Item("info")
         Dim tempBalChanges As String = drMyAcount.Item("balChange")
         Dim tempToFrom As String = drMyAcount.Item("toFrom")
         ActivityView.Rows.Add(tempDateTime, tempInfo, tempBalChanges, tempToFrom)
         rowCount = rowCount + 1 //you can still count rows in the loop
    Loop
```

Comment: I know about HasRows but it does not count the amount of rows which is what I need to do...

Comment: connecting to the Database twice , once just to get a row count is not very efficient

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not seem to specify, but apparently the `DataTable.Load` method closes the given `IDataReader` when it is done loading the data into the table.  So, once you call `dt.Load(drMyAcount)`, the `drMyAcount` will be closed.

Comment: So do you have any ideas on how to get round this?

Comment: You can either execute the command twice, or you can just read the data out of the data table rather than out of the reader.